# How many solutions in the positive integers does the equation $x^2-y^2=4k$ have?

Tags: number-theory

How many solutions in the positive integers does the equation $x^2-y^2=4k$ have, given that $k$ is an odd integer?

I want to say the answer is none, because $4(2k+1)$ is an even times an odd, and the different parity means we cannot find an integer solution to the difference of squares. Is this the right thinking? Thank you!

Comment: If you require that $x,y$ be odd then there are no solutions...the left hand will always be divisible by $8$.  But if one of them is $2m$ for odd $m$ and the other is divisible by $4$ then you get a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$(4w)^2-2^2=16w^2-4=4(4w^2-1)$ So there are clearly an infinite number of solutions.

Comment: This works provided $k$ is of the form $4w^2-1.$ [not sure if OP wants a restriction like that on $k$...]

Comment: why not? He never said anything which might discredit this solution

Comment: Jorge-- Point taken.

Comment: Jorge: there's also $(k+1)^2-(k-1)^2=4k$ without much restriction on $k$ But IMO your answer is already sufficient to show infinitely many $k$ have a solution $x,y$ to $x^2-y^2=4k.$ [And +1]

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{x^{2} - y^{2} = 4k.\quad}$ $\ds{k}$ is an $\underline{odd\ integer}$.
>   $\ds{\quad x, y\ \mbox{are integers}.\quad x, y:\ ?}$.

\begin{align}
\mbox{Lets}\quad &
\left.\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{x} & \ds{=} & \ds{u + v}
\\
\ds{y} & \ds{=} & \ds{u - v}
\end{array}\right\}
\quad\iff\quad
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{u} & \ds{=} & \ds{x + y \over 2}
\\[2mm]
\ds{v} & \ds{=} & \ds{x - y \over 2}
\end{array}\right.\,,\qquad
\mbox{Then,}\quad \bbx{\ds{uv = k}}
\end{align}

---

1. $\ds{\large k\ \underline{is\ prime}}$.

In that case we can take $\ds{u = k}$ and $\ds{v = 1 \implies x = k + 1\ \mbox{and}\ y = k - 1}$. For example: with $\ds{k = 17}$,
$$
18^{2} - 16^{2} = 324 - 256 = 68 = 4\times 17
$$

---

2. $\ds{\large k\ \underline{is\ NOT\ prime}}$.

There is, at least, some integer $\ds{\pars{~n\ \mid\ 1 < n < k~}}$ where $\ds{k/n}$ is an integer. We can take $\ds{u = \max\braces{k/n,n}}$ and
$\ds{v = k/u}$. For example, with $\ds{k = 81}$ we can take $\ds{u = 27}$ and $\ds{v = 3}$ such that $\ds{x = 30}$ and $\ds{y = 24}$:
$$
30^{2} - 24^{2} = 900 - 576 = 324 = 4 \times 81
$$

---

$$\bbx{\quad%
\mbox{The above discussion shows that there is always, at least, one solution for the original}\quad
\\
\quad\mbox{question. In addition, our answer shows a systematic procedure to find a pair}\ \ds{\pars{x,y}}.}
$$